# How to resolve error pulling GitHub docker image caused by media type from demon

Tags: github, github-package-registry

I have set up a GitHub self-hosted runner which builds docker images and pushes them to GitHub package registry:

```
      podman build --tag ${IMAGE} .
      podman login docker.pkg.github.com -u ${GITHUB_REPOSITORY} -p ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
      podman push ${IMAGE}
```

Last week I started using podman instead of docker (http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/#), but this has been running without problems on two different repositories. On the repository where I am having these problems there has been 8 deployments (which uses the docker image) on the main branch and at least as many on feature branches without any hickups. Then suddenly, yesterday: `docker pull ${IMAGE}` is giving the following:

```
Error response from daemon: mediaType in manifest should be 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' not ''
```

Is there anyone who have any suggestions on what might be causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: "_GitHub Container Registry is currently in public beta and subject to change._" quote from https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/about-github-container-registry   Maybe things will be better when the service goes into production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what kind of hiccup this was... one cannot download docker image from GitHub, but I recently build new images (not just restart of old build) and it works fine